# How to extends laravel cookie system

Tags: laravel, cookies

I want to extends laravel's cookie system to override it's methods.

In fact, I want to add a prefix to laravel's cookies automatically after creating them and read the cookie name with that prefix.

How can I do this?

I could do first step and set a cookie with prefix name by overriding the `CookieJar` class and bind it to custom service provider. But I don't know how to retrieve the cookie with that prefix?

This is my code to override CookieJar `make` method :

```
public function make($name, $value, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
{
    $name = 'prefix_' . $name;

    list($path, $domain, $secure) = $this->getPathAndDomain($path, $domain, $secure);

    $time = ($minutes == 0) ? 0 : Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() + ($minutes * 60);

    return new Cookie($name, $value, $time, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the `get` method from `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie` to

```
return static::$app['request']->cookie('prefix_' . $key, $default);
```

save that to another class and register that in place of `Cookie` alias in `config/app.php`